# How to calculate shortest path lenght of given node faster?

Tags: python, networkx, shortest-path

I'm try to find largest distance of given node by this code.

```
import networkx as nx

G= nx.read_gpickle("Database/Pickle/test.gpickle")

word = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'g', 'h', 't', 'i', 'j', 'k']
maxdistance = 0

for source in range(len(word)):
    for target in range(source+1, len(word)):

        distance = nx.dijkstra_path_length(G, word[source], word[target], weight='cost')
        if maxdistance < distance:
            maxdistance = distance

print(maxdistance)
```

I think it takes a little long time to find shortest path of each pairs, so are there anyhow to find distance faster.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a function for finding the distances from a source node to any other node. You can call the function for each source node. The function returns a dictionary of distances. Select the targets that are on the list of words, and find the largest of them:

```
maxdistance = 0
word = set(word) # Sets are faster than lists
for source in word:
    distances = nx.single_source_shortest_path_length(G, source)
    maxdistance = max(maxdistance,
                      max(v for k,v in distances.items() if k in word)
```

If `word` is a set of all nodes in the graph, just find the graph's diameter:

```
maxdistance = nx.diameter(G)
```